# What does "Received" mean in the Windows 7 Wireless Connection Status dialog?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Just a quick question, in the Windows 7 "Wireless Connection Status" dialog, under "Activity", for the number of bytes shown on the "Received" column, does it mean the entire network traffic? Or only packets for that machine?

Anyone know how can I find any MSDN or MS reference?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Received means the packets received by the network adapter. If you look at each network adapter whether there is traffic running through it you can see an individual packet count.

To answer your question, it is the network traffic from your machine.